# With Power BI DAX, how do I test if the left most characters in a field are tekst or numbers?

Tags: text, powerbi, numbers, dax

In a Power BI table I have a field with an invoice description.
The ones I need end with '......... 01-2022' (weeknumber - year).
Some end with '.....january-2022'.
I'd like to ad a column with just the weeknumbers and no tekst.
So either: 01 02 03 - 53 or blank().
What DAX function should I use to filter say 'ry' from '01'?

I have:
|......01-2022|
|......02-2022|
|january-2022|

In the new column I'd like to see:
|01|
|02|
| |
Result would be weeknumbers that I can do math with.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating this calculated column:

```
week = 
var index = FIND("-",TableName[Column],,-1)  --searching for the '-' to identify the 2 characters to test, you can modify this according to your data (if you have mutiple '-' in your text this won't work)
var totest = if(index = -1,"NA",MID(TableName[Column],index-2,2))
return if(not iserror(value(totest)),VALUE(totest),blank())
```

Make sure you figure out how to determine the position of the 2 characters to test based on your data. Once you do that, you need to update the index and totest expressions accordingly. If you're string values don't contain other "-", you can use the expressions i used.

Comment: Sharp eyes! I didn't think of looking for the '-'. I think it's always in the same place for the values I'd like to use. I'll go test.....

Comment: Works like a charm! from 49.000 lines there were 6 that didn't follow along nicely... I'll catch them somehow.

Comment: Good to hear! Could you please mark the answer as correct? Thank you!

Comment: Hi. I'd like to, I have to earn more 'reputation' it seems....